# Need help capturing the period of a wave form. (Verilog)

Tags: fpga, verilog

My code requires that I store the value of an input signal's period in a register. I have mocked up the code below to register the period, but I cant yet confirm that it works. In your experience do you see anything that is immediately wrong with it. I am trying to learn how to use modelsim at the moment please forgive me. Sys_clk is a 50MHz clock, and the in_signal I am working with right now is 2Hz but that may change.

Desired Inputs: System Clock, RST from controller, a signal of unknown frequency and duty cycle that is less than 50MHz(the freq is constant).

Desired Output: A registered period value in decimal form

```
<!-- language: verilog -->
module t_sampler(input wire in_signal, input sys_clk, output reg [31:0] total_T);

reg [31:0] pos_length;
reg [31:0] neg_length;
reg pos_cntstop;
reg neg_cntstop;


always @ (posesge sys_clk) begin

if (in_signal) begin
       pos_length <= pos_length + 1;
           end
    else begin pos_length <= pos_length;
               pos_cntstop <= 1;
         end
if (!in_signal) begin
       neg_length <= neg_length + 1;
           end
    else begin neg_length <= neg_length;
               neg_cntstop <= 1;
         end
if (neg_cntstop && pos_cntstop) begin

     total_T <= neg_length + pos_length;
     neg_cntstop <= 0;
     neg_length  <= 0;
     pos_cntstop <= 0;
     pos_length  <= 0;

     end
end
endmodule
```

Comment: Point out the behaviour of in_signal, because when 1 cycle complete pos_length will be changed. You should latch the values of both counter on respective counter stop.

Comment: Thank you prakash. Could you maybe demonstrate that with a small segment of code. Im fried. I appreciate your help

Comment: Sure, just upload timing diagram of your all signals.

Comment: I am looking for a code example in Verilog and test bench. I can't seem to find an example of what I am trying to do that is just a straightforward period capture. Inputs to the module are: a 50MHz system clock for sampling and reference, a rst from controller, and an input signal of unknown duty cycle and frequency that is less than 50MHz.

The output is the period registered in decimal form. It would be nice if the testbench output the value so I could see it. I haven't really worked with $dipslay much

Comment: THere's lots of code here. How about a minimum example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Provide your test bench. It's something everyone who uses Verilog knows, so you will have to loon soon.

Answer (score 0):

There are several items you will need to address.

Assuming that the input signal is asynchronous with the clock signal, you will need to use a couple of flop-flops to synchronize the input edges to the clock.  You can add a third flip-flop and decode to create a 1 clock cycle pulse that occurs at each rising edge of the input signal.

This will simplify your counter circuit; you will need only one counter, because counting the clocks between the two pulses will correspond to one period.

As Prakesh mentions in the comments above, you will need to latch the counter results because the counter value will continue to change with each clock cycle.

Comment: I am really struggling to understand. Do i latch them by inverting their value?

Comment: @metaeyo : tell us behaviour of `in_signal` then we can address you the solution.

Comment: Its the output from a 50% duty cycle clock divider. Right now I have it divided down to 2Hz but it will be changed when I implement it. I simply divided the 50MHz system clock to 2Hz. I am working on an offline computer or else I would upload a timing table. I want the period sampler to sample any frequency though so the 2Hz is parameterized